# In JavaScript OOP is it bad practice to use the "this" keyword to reference a method?

Tags: javascript

I know that ***this*** is usually used to reference data within the same object.
Are there any cases where ***this*** can reference methods inside the object, not props?
What are the pluses and minuses of doing that?

```js
var person = {
  name: "John",
  showName() {
    return this.name;
  },
  showNameAgain() {
    return this.showName();
  }
};


console.log( person.showName() );

console.log( person.showNameAgain() );
```

Comment: Using `this` to refer to methods is **extremely** common; it's a basic part of JavaScript programming with objects.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't use `this` to reference any methods... it does *call* a method though...

Comment: @GregBurghardt you can't call a method without acquiring a reference to it ...

Comment: There are no existential programming problems, just code readability and performance issues

Comment: I think you need to read [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: @Pointy: I'm not clear what the OP means by "this can reference methods inside the object" then. I assumed he mean to pass or return a reference to the method rather than invoke it: `return this.showName` versus `this.showName()`

Comment: I also don't know what "this can reference methods inside the object" is trying to say

Comment: @GregBurghardt sure; I don't really understand the issue either. It seems like a few minutes of reading almost any JavaScript tutorial about objects and inheritance would turn up lots of ordinary uses of `this`.